# SQL query to LINQ (complex for me)

Tags: c#, linq, sql-to-linq-conversion

I am a very new to LINQ, I have done simple queries, but I have hit a wall on this one.  Could someone help me convert this to LINQ?  Joining the table to itself and the counting of records has me hung.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
     RegionID = O.Region,
     Region = R.Office,
     OfficeCount = (SELECT
          COUNT(officeID)
          FROM OFfice
          WHERE Region = O.region
          AND Type IN (5, 6)
          AND ClosedProduction = 0
          AND OfficeID NOT IN (10, 135, 151)
          AND (OfficeID IN (SELECT DISTINCT
                    OfficeID
                    FROM WR_Data_Work
                    WHERE PhaseID IS NOT NULL)
          OR OfficeID = 154))
     FROM office O
     JOIN Office R
     ON O.Region = R.OfficeID
     JOIN Employee VP
     ON R.VicePresID = VP.EmployeeID
     WHERE O.OfficeID NOT IN (10, 135, 151)
     AND O.Type IN (5, 6)
     AND O.ClosedProduction = 0
     AND (O.OfficeID IN (SELECT DISTINCT
                         OfficeID
                         FROM WR_Data_Work
                         WHERE PhaseID IS NOT NULL)
     OR O.OfficeID = 154)
ORDER BY RegionID
```

```
OfficeID    OfficeName  Region
88          Office 1    90
90          Office 2    90
96          Office 3    90
86          Office 4    93
91          Office 5    93
92          Office 6    93
93          Office 7    93
95          Office 8    93
```

In this case, Office 2 is a regional office for offices 1 and 3, but office 7 is a regional office for 4, 5, 6 and 8.

Comment: This could be done in Linq, but consider just implementing a Stored proc or view and calling that from EF.  These days I avoid Views and stored procs, but if you can't figure out a solution in linq, then it's a good fallback.

Comment: @AaronLS - I agree entirely. I rarely use stored procedures, as most of it can be done through LINQ to SQL, however in the instances like the OP, a stored procedure is usually just the right tool to use

Comment: Write each of the queries separately, and use the results in the appropriate part of the overall query. The deferred execution should unravel it all to what it should be. Probably make it more readable as well

Comment: This query doesn't make sense, it seems to be mixing Office and Region identifiers. I'd like to see a class diagram for the entity model before I propose and answer to this / perhaps at least a fix to the oddities.

Comment: Edited the original post to clarify.   It appears to be mixing Office and Region identifiers because every office is an office, some offices are a regional office.

Comment: If you look at your query you select columns "RegionID, Region, OfficeCount" ... I'm not sure how you get "OfficeID, OfficeName, Region" from this SQL. Please provide a MVCE, perhaps use something like SQLFiddle.com to show us how this is intended to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my try without any ability to test:

```
var PhaseOffices = (from w in WR_Data_Work where w.PhaseID != null select w.OfficeID).Distinct();
var TargetOffices = from O in Office
                    where (O.Type == 5 || O.Type == 6) && O.ClosedProduction == 0 &&
                    (!(new[] { 10, 135, 151 }).Contains(O.OfficeID)) && (PhaseOffices.Contains(O.OfficeID) || O.OfficeID == 154)
                    select O;

var res = (from O in TargetOffices
          join R in Office on O.Region equals R.OfficeID
          //join VP in Employee on R.VicePresID equals VP.EmployeeID = not needed?
          orderby O.Region
          select new {
              RegionID = O.Region,
              Region = R.Office,
              OfficeCount = (from ofc in TargetOffices
                             where ofc.Region == O.Region
                             select ofc.OfficeID).Count()
           }).Distinct();
```

Some LINQ Providers won't handle the local array `Contains` I used, in which case you'll have to replace it with individual tests like I did with `Type`.

Comment: Worked almost perfectly.  It's missing the Distinct on the Region, but that was easy to add at the end.  Thanks!!!

Comment: Where do you have that in the SQL statement? I only saw the one that was part of the `PhaseOffices` `SELECT`. Maybe you meant the `ORDER BY`? I did leave that off...

Comment: Isn't that what the first distinct does?  The second word in the query?  It seems to act that way in MSSQL.

Comment: Yes, somehow I overlooked that one.